# How to select records by multiple attributes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm not a backend programmer, but I need to solve this problem. For me it was more complicated than it seemed at the beginning.

I have some linked SQL tables:

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tools` (
`id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`cat` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tools` (`id`, `cat`, `name`) VALUES
('1', '17', 'jackhammer 70'),
('2', '17', 'jackhammer 75'),
('3', '17', 'jackhammer 90');
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS attributes (
    id int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `attributes` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
('1', 'weight'),
('2', 'type'),
('3', 'model');
```

**Table 3**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attribute_values` (
`attr_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`tool_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `attribute_values` (`attr_id`, `tool_id`, `value`) VALUES
('1', '1', '70'),
('2', '1', 'manual'),
('3', '1', 'ABC'),
('1', '2', '75'),
('2', '2', 'manual'),
('3', '2', 'DEF'),
('1', '3', '90'),
('2', '3', 'automatic'),
('3', '3', 'HIG');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bfd368/1

How can I select all records from `tools` table where attribute `weight` is less then 80 and `type` is manual.

Attributes like `weight` are stored in a table attributes and their values in table `attribute_values`

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online on how to do simple SQL select queries.

Comment: Can you give an code snippet, if it is so easy?

Comment: How do you want weight to be less then 80? You have a col named `name` with an `id`

Comment: attributes are stored in a table `attributes` and their values in table `attribute_values`

Comment: I think your table `attribute_values` will create a problem. Because the values(`value`) that it contains are probably `VARCHAR`, so you will be ablwe to check for `attr_id = 2 AND type = 'manual'`, but you can not check `weight` coz it's a `VARCHAR`. So, you'd need to change your table structre or `typecast the value to INT on attr_id 1` if MYSQL allows it!

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
SELECT * FROM tools 
WHERE id IN(
  SELECT tool_id FROM attributes a
  INNER JOIN attribute_values av
  WHERE a.name = 'weight'
  AND CAST(av.value AS UNSIGNED) < 80
) 
AND id IN(
  SELECT tool_id FROM attributes a
  INNER JOIN attribute_values av
  WHERE a.name = 'type'
  AND av.value = 'manual'
);
```

Your types are going to present a problem. You can't do a varchar for everything. You should consider making a better schema to store your data for your use case. Or type cast, but that is going to be a performance hit.

Also, this is known as an [EAV data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) and should not be used in most cases -- in fact I've found few cases that warrant using such a model. It gets messy fast and MySQL is not the datastore to use for it. Use row based modeling instead.

Comment: How can this `AND av.value < 80` work, it's a `VARCHAR`? Also, it's throwing error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM tools WHERE id IN( SELECT tool_id FROM attributes a INNER JOI' at line 6`!

Comment: It is too slowly - more then 2 minutes in table `tools` with about 5000 records

Comment: We are having to cast a datatype and search on a poorly designed schema. We have everything working against us. The best thing to do is to redo the schema and apply proper indexes for performance. We can then write a more optimal query to retrieve the data. I gave you a way to solve the problem. Unfortunately your problem goes deeper than just being able to write a MySQL query.